# como usar correctamente POSTMAN con variables POST en PHP?

Tags: php, post, postman

tengo la siguiente url

http://www.upper-three.com/UriDent/json/nuevo.php

tiene el siguiente código

```
<?php
$username  =  $_POST['username'];

$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "2";
$response["username"] = $username;

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

y me devuelve esto

```
{"success":1,"message":"2","username":null}
```

estoy intentando usar POSTMAN para poder realizar el envió de la variable POST username

pero sin resultado.

ejemplo 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejemplo 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

algún comentario ?

Comment: intenta cambiando el `header` antes del `return` así `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: Hola. lo agregue . pero sin resultados.    :(

Comment: haz un print_r($_POST) y ve que te trae

Comment: lo agregue .. y solo poner la url en el explorador me devuelve  Array{"success":1,"message":"2","username":null}  .. pero con el postman.. {"success":1,"message":"2","username":null},,,

Comment: comenta ahorita tu respuesta de json_encode para que no haya confusión, pon el print_r($_POST) solamente y pruebalo en el postman

Comment: lo cambie y solo deje header('Content-Type: application/json');

$username  =  $_POST['username'];

print_r($_POST) 

y usando postman no me da resultado.. quizás estoy haciendo algo mal en postman

Comment: Quita también el header para testear, ya que espera como respuesta un json,

Comment: lo quite pero sin resultado.  hasta el momento el código quedo ..$username  =  $_POST['username'];

print_r($_POST)     solo eso

Comment: Intenta con esto
`$params = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
print_r($params);` en lugar del print_r($_POST);